# Where do I put common Methods in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am used to having static methods in the App_Code folder, this folder is no longer available in MVC template. These static methods I use all over the site.

How is it done in MVC, what is the best practice?
How do you call the common methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically I will have one or more class library projects in the same solution to hold auxiliary classes.  Create your classes in a class library project, then reference that project's DLL in your MVC web application.  The exception to this would be any models, actual or view-only.  These could be put in the Models folder.

Comment: I actually end up putting my model in a separate assembly and have my ViewModel in my model folder. But that's neither here nor there in terms of the question.

Answer (score 6):

I usually make a class called Utility that contains static methods that don't seem to fit anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on size of your app. For small app just create a folder and put your classes inside it; If you have a lot of classes - create separate project for them.

Answer (score 1):

As @tvanfosson said have a different project and have all your class libraries there, but if you want to keep it simple you can create a Folder within your project and save all your .cs/.vb files inside the folder

Answer (score 1):

My methods usually fall into 3 areas in MVC; business methods, controller flow, and presentation.

My business methods go in services, if there is global logic I consolidate it into a single service, maybe with a group of hidden services behind it.

For controller logic I create extension methods against Controller.

For presentation I create extension methods attached to the html helper and call them with <%= Html.MyCustomPresentationMethod() %>